# Возврат на страницу заполнения формы заказа при отмене платежа

Tags: php, yii2

Есть проблема. Нужно, при нажитии человеком кнопки "отмена платежа", возвращать человека на страницу заполнения данных для заказа, при этом форма заказа, должна быть заполнена как до перенаправления на плетежную систему.

Вот как это должно выглядить:

1) Мы заполняем форму заказа и в ней выбираем платежную систему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае выбрана кредитная карта.

2) Мы нажимаем кнопку оформления заказа (зеленая) и нас редиректит на страницу оплаты, которая находится на внешнем сервисе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Допустим, человек случайно ошибся с методом оплаты и хочет выбрать другой. Он нажимает кнопку "Abort" (то, что в красной рамочке) и его должно вернуть на заполненную форму заказа на нашем сайте, чтобы он смог выбрать другой метод оплаты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовала сделать это функцией `window.history.back()`, но появляется ошибка о том, что я пытаюсь переотправить форму. Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сохранял данные формы куда-то (сессии, бд, etc) и заполнял модель формы ими
Предупреждение возникает из-за того что вы возвращаетесь на момент отправки (нужно на одну запись больше возвращаться)